# .NET-Core: Running the built application in PostBuildEvent

Tags: msbuild, .net-core, csproj

I have an `Exe` project that I would like to run in the `PostBuildEvent` block.  I have tried adding a command to do this several ways but nothing seems to work.

```
dotnet run -- -i
dotnet run TestConsole.csproj -- -i
dotnet run ../../../TestConsole.csproj -- -i
../../../init.bat (which contains a cd to the project directory and "dotnet run...")
```

The first two fail being unable to find anything to run.  The last two fail by hanging.  Apparently, `dotnet build` recursively calling `dotnet run` doesn't work very well.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to re-use the built-in targets that already calculate the command. `dotnet run` also builds the project, so calling `dotnet run` could cause an infinite recursion - instead it should be `dotnet path/to/the.dll`. Also, `PostBuildEvent` is considered deprecated and has [problems in SDK-based projects](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/1569) (an [upcoming VS update will add targets instead](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/pull/2367) when adding post build commands).

To execute the program on build, you can add the following to the csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <!-- other project content -->

  <Target Name="RunAfterBuild" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="$(RunCommand) $(RunArguments)" WorkingDirectory="$(RunWorkingDirectory)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The `AfterTargets="Build"` will cause to to run after ever build, even if it is invoked through VS. If it should not be run when working on the project in VS, you could add

```
Condition=" '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true' "
```

as an attribute to the `<Target>` element.

The values for `$(RunCommand)`, `$(RunArguments)` and `$(RunWorkingDirectory)` [are defaulted by the SDK](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/79d2f9e93433ff198516f2defccf9fe37c20a887/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets#L281-L320) and contain the right paths to the host / exe file etc. involved. You can add any custom parameters to the `Command="..."` attribute and they will be passed to the application (no `--` needed).

In order to add global arguments that would also be respected when the project was built/run through `dotnet` run, the `StartArguments` property in the project can be set. it will be added to `RunArguments` automatically:

```
<Project …>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartArguments>--sample-option</StartArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- other content -->
</Project>
```

Comment: I think I saw this online somewhere but I didn't understand where this gets added.  Is it a top-level child of `Project`?  Is it under an `ItemGroup`?  Under `PropertyGroup`?  Where is this documented?  Also, how do I then invoke it?  Is it automatically run after every build?

Comment: In addition, how would I set the `RunCommand`, `RunArguments`, and `RunWorkingDirectory` macros?

Comment: MSBuild documentation is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-concepts.
There is also a [document about the exec task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task)

Comment: Thanks, @martin-ullrich, I think this gave me the boost I needed.